# I can not set a jumbotron background image in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple HTML page and I want to set to my "jumbotron" a background image, but it does not work.

I use the PhpStrom IDE, using a Bootstrap 4.0 BETA installation. The -s are set properly in the  section, the custom CSS file has been set after the bootstrap css link.

I am clueless, I think it should has been working, but it has not.

My HTML is:

```css
.ipcs {
    background-image: url("/pics/animals.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron ipcs">
 <h1 class="display-3" >LOREM IPSUM</h1 >
 <p class="lead" >.................</p >
 <hr class="my-2" >
 
 <p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut consequatur deleniti ea exercitationem impedit
     molestiae neque pariatur ratione unde, velit? Amet delectus, doloribus eveniet minus numquam quas quis ratione
     suscipit!</p >
</div >
</div>
```

Comment: works fine here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/mbjdhuq8/15/**

Comment: Define the problem more clearly: What is (or is not) happening? Troubleshoot - use your browser's developer console to inspect the element - is the style you've defined set on the element? Check the network tab - is the file loading properly, or is it resulting in a 404 not found or other error?

Comment: Well, i have just inspected the code in my chrome browser, and the consol contained an error message:  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND --- animals.png

Comment: I think the problem is the uncertain url notation. There are relative and absolute path notation in html and in CSS as well. The correct on would be "../pics/animals.png". I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

you are close to the money according to your comment i quote

"Well, i have just inspected the code in my chrome browser, and the consol contained an error message: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND --- animals.png"

means that the background image your are trying to place cannot be found , you can run a troubleshoot to confirm this by replacing the background image link with online placeholder generators like http://placehold.it/500x300

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was the relative-absolute path problem. The picture's path has to be calculated from the relative path of the CSS file's directory.
If the directory structure is the fllowing

```
/project/css/custom.css ....
/project/pics/animals.png ....
/project/index.html ....
```

you have to set the URL definition in the CSS file like this:

```
.customJumbotron {
backround-image : url("../pics/animals.png");
}
```

The first .. takes you one directory "higher", the you can set the picture file's url from there. That was the problem. The first slash has to be omitted in this case.

Small things matter...